# Can I use safeTransfer from OpenZeppelin to send ETH along with ERC20 token?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, transfer

My contract holds tokenA + ETH. Right now I pay users this way:

```
tokenAcontract.safeTransfer(wallet, amountTokenA); // tokenA
Address.sendValue(wallet, amountETH); // ETH
```

Can I do it in one single step, keeping it safe or is it already the most optimized way to send both ETH and ERC20 tokens?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no safe way of doing this all-in-one-transaction, because either the transaction will fail (because most ERC20 methods are ***not payable***), or the `ether` will be stuck in an ERC20's `Proxy` contract (because usually `Proxy`'s *delegate* `fallback` is payable, however it doesn't forward the funds to the recipient).

E.g.:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

// File: zos-lib/contracts/upgradeability/Proxy.sol

/**
 * @title Proxy
 * @dev Implements delegation of calls to other contracts, with proper
 * forwarding of return values and bubbling of failures.
 * It defines a fallback function that delegates all calls to the address
 * returned by the abstract _implementation() internal function.
 */
contract Proxy {
  /**
   * @dev Fallback function.
   * Implemented entirely in `_fallback`.
   */
  function () payable external {
    _fallback();
  }

  /**
   * @return The Address of the implementation.
   */
  function _implementation() internal view returns (address);

  /**
   * @dev Delegates execution to an implementation contract.
   * This is a low level function that doesn't return to its internal call site.
   * It will return to the external caller whatever the implementation returns.
   * @param implementation Address to delegate.
   */
  function _delegate(address implementation) internal {
    assembly {
      // Copy msg.data. We take full control of memory in this inline assembly
      // block because it will not return to Solidity code. We overwrite the
      // Solidity scratch pad at memory position 0.
      calldatacopy(0, 0, calldatasize)

      // Call the implementation.
      // out and outsize are 0 because we don't know the size yet.
      let result := delegatecall(gas, implementation, 0, calldatasize, 0, 0)

      // Copy the returned data.
      returndatacopy(0, 0, returndatasize)

      switch result
      // delegatecall returns 0 on error.
      case 0 { revert(0, returndatasize) }
      default { return(0, returndatasize) }
    }
  }

  /**
   * @dev Function that is run as the first thing in the fallback function.
   * Can be redefined in derived contracts to add functionality.
   * Redefinitions must call super._willFallback().
   */
  function _willFallback() internal {
  }

  /**
   * @dev fallback implementation.
   * Extracted to enable manual triggering.
   */
  function _fallback() internal {
    _willFallback();
    _delegate(_implementation());
  }
}
```

That is the code of the `USDC`'s `FiatProxy` contract. *(They use it for `Upgradeable` implementations.)*

**!** *You can see the `fallback` function is payable here, so your ETH will be stuck if your forward it along with the `ERC20` token *transfer* call.*